# como abrir uma nova pagina clicando num elemento duma tabela

Tags: jquery-datatables

como é que faço para selecionar uma row no datatables e abrir com maiores detalhes o conteúdo por um ID.

tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura

nome ,id , morada ,utilizador.

com valores .

Ao clicar pertendo abrir um poupop  em javascript onde ser feita uma nova consulta a uma base de dados passando o id como parametero.

Comment: podem ajudar-me

Comment: Sua dúvida não está clara. Mostre o que você já fez (poste seu código) e esclareca exatamente qual o problema que você quer resolver.

Comment: basicamente ao clicar numa tr da tabela abre um poupop onde vai carregar o resto das informações fazendo uma query  a base de dados

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar recurso do próprio HTML, como mostrado abaixo:

```
<table>
<tr onclick="window.location='página destino aqui'">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```